# Python regex find all matches

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7 re library to find all numbers written in scientific form in a string. I'm using the following code:

```
import re
y = re.findall(".([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+).","{8.25e+07|8.26206e+07}")
print y
```

However, the output is only `['8.25e+07']` while I'm expecting something like `[('8.25e+07'),(8.26206e+07)]`. I've been trying around but couldn't find where the problem is. If I input `y = re.findall(".([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+).","|8.26206e+07}")` then it gives `['8.26206e+07']` so the pattern is matching the second number but I don't get it why it doesn't match both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are slightly overcomplicating your regex by misusing the `.` which matches any character while not actually needing it and using a capturing group `()` without really using it.

With your pattern you are looking for a number in scientific notation which has to be BOTH preceded and followed by exactly one character.

```
{8.25e+07|8.26206e+07}
[--------]
```

After `re.findall` traverses your string from the beginning it finds your defined pattern, which then drops the `{` and the `|` because of your capturing group `(..)` and saves this as a match. It then continues but only has `8.26206e+07}` left. That now does not satisfy your pattern, because it is missing one "any" character for your first `.`, and no further match is found. Note that `findall` only looks for `non-overlapping matches`[1].

To illustrate, change your input string by duplicating your separator `|`:

```
>>> p = ".([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)."
>>> s = "{8.25e+07||8.26206e+07}"
>>> print(re.findall(p, s))
['8.25e+07', '8.26206e+07']
```

To satisfy your two `.`s you need two separators between any two numbers.

Two things I would change in your pattern, (1) remove the `.`s and (2) remove your capturing group `(` `)`, you have no need for it:

```
p = "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+"
```

Capturing groups can be very useful if you need to refer to specific captured groups again later, but your task at hand has no need for them.

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall

Answer (score 1):

Because `findall` is documented to

> ... Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

But your patterns overlap: the leading `.` of the second match would have to be the `|` character, but that was already consumed by the trailing `.` of the first match.

Just remove those non-captured `.`s at the start and end of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have extra dots. 
try this below

```
import re
y = re.findall("([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)","{8.25e+07|8.26206e+07}")
print (y)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use regular expressions to match. The default mode will be to find all **non-overlapping** matches. Using the dots at both the end and the beginning, you make them overlap.

```
"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)"
```

should work